# CiviBooking: self-service bookings?

Tags: permissions, acl, user, civibooking

Use case: we’d like anonymous (or, if necessary, authenticated) users to be able to create provisional bookings, but not to edit anyone else’s.
In the Drupal access control, “create and update” is a single permission, and it appears to be for all bookings, not just those created by a user.  Correct?
ACL would seem to be able to address this, but it’s not clear how/whether ACL has control over CiviBooking data. Anyone have insight?
Any suggestions, either for how to configure things or (if need be) how to explore modifying the code?
We’re using Drupal 6, CiviCRM 1.4.6, and CiviBooking 1.5
Thanks!

Comment: Did you discover whether this is possible?